# Как получить перевод категории WordPress плагином Polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress, multilanguage, polylang

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с выводом подкатегорий плагином Polylang.

Нужно выводить все посты из текущей подкатегории на выбранном языке и отображать только текущую подкатегорию.

На основном языке все выводится отлично, как нужно, записи из указанной подкатегории, а при переключение на другой язык получаем вывод всех категорий с постами(как на родительской странице блога), в чем беда, что я делаю не так ?
Структура следующая CATEGORY—SUBCATEGORY—POST
Спасибо!

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'post',
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby'   => 'date',
'cat'   => pll_get_term(68),
'lang'  =>pll_current_language()            
)); ?>

<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>

<div class="category_faq_card">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata()?>
```

Comment: Если создаю отдельный файл с шаблоном для подкатегории на определенном языке - работает...

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обязательно установите перевод в категории. Должен подтянуться

Comment: все переводы были изначально добавлены как вы показали выше, это не помогло.